# How to mock a function only once in a test suite?

Tags: node.js, mocking, jestjs

I'm writing integration tests for a project. Within one test suite, I'm invoking a register endpoint in multiple tests. Most of the time I want to test what the actual response of the `registerUser` function is given certain `req` parameters.

This all works fine except I also want to test what happens if the `registerUser` function throws an error. I know I can mock the `registerUser` function on top of the test suite but this will affect all tests. I've tried to play around with `jest.mock` and `jest.spyOn` but I could not get it to work yet.

How can I mock the response of the `registerUser` function once and restore it afterwards so it doesn't affect the other tests in the suite?

*authController.js*

```
router.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const response = await registerUser(req);
        res.status(HttpStatus.OK).json({ response });
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).json({ err });
    }
});
```

*authController.test.js*

```
const faker = require('faker');
const HttpStatus = require('http-status-codes');
const authService = require('../services/authService');

// -- Tests where the response of the registerUser function are not mocked are here -- //

it('Gives a status code 500 when an unexpected error is thrown', async () => {
    const registerUserMock = jest.spyOn(authService, "registerUser");
    registerUserMock.mockReturnValue(() => new Error('Oh snap! Something went wrong.'));

    const res = await agent.post('/register')
        .send({
            email: faker.internet.email(),
            firstname: faker.name.firstName(),
            lastname: faker.name.lastName(),
            password: '123',
            reTypedPassword: '123',
        });

    expect(res.statusCode).toBe(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    
    registerUserMock.mockRestore();
});

// -- more tests -- //
```

Comment: What exactly did not work with jest.spyOn? You omitted authService that is relevant here. It's unknown how registerUser is defined and imported.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way would be to

1. group the tests which should use the same mocked response in a suite (describe)
2. mock the response in that suite's `beforeAll` hook and save the mock instance
3. restore the original implementation in that suite's `afterAll` hook.

```js
describe('tests with successful auth result', () => {

    let authSpy;

    beforeAll(() => {
        authSpy = jest.spyOn(authService, "registerUser").mockReturnValue(...);
    });

    afterAll(() => {
        authSpy.mockRestore();
    });

    // tests using successful result

});

describe('tests with failing auth result', () => {
    // same but with different spy result
});
```

note two important things:

- you need to call `mockRestore` on the *mock instance* returned from `mockReturnValue`, not on the initial spy value
- it's best to setup the mock in `beforeEach` / `beforeAll` and restore it in `afterEach`  /`afterAll`, because if you set and restore it directly in the test (`it`), then if the test fails the spy remains unrestored, and may affect the following tests!